# Adding text message on TeeChart

Tags: java, android, teechart

I'm evaluating TeeChart Java for Android.
In some cases data can be unavailable for my chart. In this case **I should display a message to user. What is the easiest way to do this with TeeChart?**

I've tried to use `textOut()` method but the problem is that the message I want to display can be wider than a chart control, but text wrapping doesn't occur in this case. As the result, I have my message displayed out of the bounds of the chart:

```
String text = ...;
IGraphics3D g = chart.getGraphics3D();
g.textOut(g.getXCenter() - (g.textWidth(text) / 2), g.getYCenter() - (g.textHeight(text) / 2), text);
```

Also I've tried to use an annotation tool, but there was a problem with aligning the annotation in the center of the chart. By the way, how do I force my chart to be redrawn?

Answer (score 1):

Here there are two ways to achieve it. I'm actually doing the same you suggested: using an Annotation tool and drawing directly the text on the canvas, at ChartPaintListener:

```
private void testMessage() {
    final String message = "This is a message for the user";

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    final int mLeft = metrics.widthPixels/2 - tChart1.getGraphics3D().textWidth(message)/2;
    final int mTop = metrics.heightPixels/2 - tChart1.getGraphics3D().textHeight(message)/2 - 100;


    final Annotation annot = new Annotation(tChart1.getChart());
    annot.setText(message);
    annot.getShape().setCustomPosition(true);
    annot.setLeft(mLeft);
    annot.setTop(mTop);

    tChart1.addChartPaintListener(new ChartPaintAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void chartPainted(ChartDrawEvent e) {
            tChart1.getGraphics3D().textOut(mLeft, mTop-50, message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Yeray. But what if my message should be wrapped because the width of a text is bigger than the width of canvas? Also please note that my chart is resizable, so I should maintain label's position every time when user resizes the chart.

Comment: @Dennis, have you tried to do the calculations inside `chartPainted()`? You can cut the string in `message` while `metrics.widthPixels<tChart1.getGraphics3D().textWidth(message)`

Comment: yes I've tried. Should I cut the string by myself or there's a way to wrap the string into multiple lines automatically?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a TeeChart function to do this